# Oracle Trigger Subquery problem

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, subquery

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "DISC_CLIENT"
BEFORE INSERT ON "PURCHASE"
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
checkclient PURCHASE.CLIENTNO%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT Clientno INTO checkclient
FROM PURCHASE
GROUP BY ClientNo
HAVING SUM(Amount)=(SELECT MAX(SUM(Amount)) FROM PURCHASE GROUP BY Clientno);
IF :new.ClientNo = checkclient
new.Amount := (:old.Amount * 0.90);
END IF;
END;
/
```

Seem to be having a problem with this trigger. I know there I cant use the WHEN() clause for subqueries so im hoping this would work but it doesnt! Ideas anyone? :/

Basically im trying to get this trigger to apply a discount to the amount value before inserting if the client matches the top client! : )

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by this trigger? I would suppose that you want to give a 10% price discount to the client who spent the most money in your shop. But this trigger won't do it - trigger can't change :new and :old values and :old is empty for insert trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a non-pretty but easy way round this, create a view and update that. You can then explicitly state all the columns in your trigger and put them in the table. You'd also be much better off creating a 1 row 2 column table, `max_amount` and then inserting the maximum amount and `clientno` into that each time. You should also really have a discounted amount column in the purchase table, as you ought to know who you've given discounts to. The amount charged is then `amount - discount`. This get's around both the mutating table and being unable to update `:new.amount` as well as making your queries much, much faster. As it stands you don't actually apply a discount if the current transaction is the highest, only if the client has placed the previous highest, so I've written it like that.

```
create or replace view purchase_view as
  select *
    from purchase;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_PURCHASE_INSERT
  BEFORE INSERT ON PURCHASE_VIEW
  FOR EACH ROW

  DECLARE

  checkclient max_amount.clientno%type;
  checkamount max_amount.amount%type;
  discount    purchase.discount%type;

  BEGIN

    SELECT clientno, amount
      INTO checkclient, checkamount
      FROM max_amount;

   IF :new.clientno = checkclient then
      discount := 0.1 * :new.amount;
   ELSIF :new.amount > checkamount then
      update max_amount
         set clientno = :new.clientno
           , maxamount = :new.amount
             ; 
    END IF;

    -- Don-t specify columns so it breaks if you change
    -- the table and not the trigger
    insert into purchase 
    values ( :new.clientno
           , :new.amount
           , discount
           , :new.other_column );
END TR_PURCHASE_INSERT;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

As I remember  a trigger can't select from a table it's fired for.
Otherwise you'll get ORA-04091: table XXXX is mutating, trigger/function may not see it. Tom [advises](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:9579487119866) us not to put too much logic into triggers.

And if I understand your query, it should be like this:

```
SELECT Clientno INTO checkclient
FROM PURCHASE
GROUP BY ClientNo
HAVING SUM(Amount)=(select max (sum_amount) from (SELECT SUM(Amount) as sum_amount FROM PURCHASE GROUP BY Clientno));
```

This way it will return the client who spent the most money.

But I think it's better to do it this way:

```
select ClientNo
from (
  select ClientNo, sum (Amount) as sum_amount
  from PURCHASE
  group by ClientNo)
order by sum_amount
where rownum
```